# Toggle Fullscreen custom keyboard shortcut broken in 14.04, 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, keyboard, shortcuts, fullscreen

Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 do not recognize custom keyboard shortcut for `Toggle fullscreen mode`.

Other custom shortcuts, like `Toggle maximization state`, are working properly.

I've tried setting the custom shortcut to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>, and many others.

To test:

- go to `Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Windows`
- set `Toggle fullscreen mode` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (or anything else)
- test whether the shortcut actually works on FireFox (or any other program).

bug report at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1615865

Comment: Is there a bug report on launchpad?

Comment: @Matteo

Yes - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1615865

Answer (score 3):

Well all you need is a **compizconfig-settings-manager** and plugin  [compiz-fusion-plugins-extra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/x11/compiz-fusion-plugins-extra)

```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Open compiz on Windows Management tab, activate ***Extra WM actions*** plugin by checking the box.

set keybind action "Toggle Fullscreen" on Extra WM actions page. Log out and login again

P.S. for gnome shell use **gconf** or try **dconf** to bind key

**Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04**

[original text link for old versions](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1497976&p=10188690#post10188690%)

Comment: The answer you are linking to is from prior to the release of 14.04, 16.04. Did you test this on a more current release? If so, it would be useful to [edit] your current steps and results into your answer. Thank you.

Comment: done, but I can't test on 14.04 because it also old version, but I think that it should work too.

Comment: I can attest to the fact that 14.04 works as well.